# Wordpress as heavily personalized content management portal, and somewhat like dropbox

Tags: plugins, wp-admin, plugin-recommendation

My background is not that of a Web-developer (either UI or backend), though I've dabbled a bit in PHP. So please help me improve this question if required.

I am trying to evaluate if Wordpress (with a selection of certain plugins), may be a good choice as a heavily personalized content management portal, bordering in some "Dropbox-like" (the cloud storage service) functionalities.

The web-portal I am looking for, would allow authorized subscribers to upload their files, while also allowing the administrator to upload, remove, archive such files from the subscriber accounts. The subscribers can access only content in their account, unless they are invited by another subscriber. I expect to have thousands, or even tens of thousands of such subscribers.

**Edit *(July 21, 2013)***

To add to the requirements, which weren't very clear initially, I need Wordpress for other things as well, though, I could always limit use of Wordpress to only these additional functionalities (that one expects of a typical Wordpress site):

- Selectively publish (some of the) files, and invite comments on -- on social network sites s.a. Facebook, Twitter, Google+ etc.
- Create diary, with a sense of time-line of events, with reference to files -- some of the diary entries could be public/shared-with-friends or be absolutely private
- Host an ecommerce storefront, via which increased storage could be sold by hosting firm, apart from a marketplace for subscribers to put up some of the content/files (example -- rare vintage photographs/videos) on sale, for other subscribers to purchase.

Finally, if something like this could be achieved with Wordpress, could someone suggest the plugins that I might look at ? If there are alternatives, then knowing about them would help too.

Is there a consolidated source of Wordpress plugins with detailed description, documentation, use-cases and perhaps some FAQ (in the CPAN sense, for those familiar with the Perl world).

Answer (score 1):

I am sure that you could do this with WordPress, but this is far from what WordPress was built to do.

Your description makes it sound like you would not be using most of WordPress. I don't see any mention of posts, or any mention of public content at all actually. You wouldn't need posts, pages, feeds, taxonomies, most everything.

I don't think that the effort needed to undo what WordPress does by default and convert it into online file sharing/hosting would be worth it. You wouldn't have much WordPress left, meaning you would have a lot of bloat and I'd expect that to result in a very inefficient system.

I doubt that "a selection of certain plugins" for doing something like what you describe would result in anything but a cobbled together mess. You'd need to make your own. That though, takes us back to point #1, that this is far from what WordPress was built to do.

Unless you have left a lot out of the description, WordPress does not sound like what you need.

Comment: Appreciate your taking time to answer. I do understand that the features I mentioned are not typical of what one expect Wordpress to do. However, I got the impression that plugins do help extend Wordpress's capabilities (and use-cases) quite significantly. Also, I've clarified/expanded my question on aspects which I believe are more aligned with Wordpress' raison d'etre.

Comment: @icarus74 : I took a look at your edit. That is making more use of WordPress than it first seemed but it is still fairly distant. You state that your "background is not that of a Web-developer". It would need to be, or you'd likely need to hire someone. I doubt that any collection of plugins would do this, much less do it well. It is just too specialized.

Comment: Fair enough. While I was hopeful of a Wordpress based solution to my needs, but "not possible/easily/elegantly" is an equally valid answer. I'll keep the question open for a little longer, and then perhaps, accept this.

Answer (score 0):

@icarus74 you should really take care of the points mentioned above by @s_ha_dum. And still If you want to use the WP you can use http://owncloud.org/ for your own Dropbox typo solution.

For Ecommerce store front you can use Woocommerce plugin or "MarketPress eCommerce".

Thanks

Comment: Please explain _why_ you're recommending those plugins and links mentioned above. Thanks.